# Can't find the stickers!

Tags: stickers

I have an *Indiana Jones 8+ 77012* box, but I checked for the stickers and there weren't any of them for the fighter plane, the car, and the sign for Berlin in the box or lego bags, I remember that someone from my Mom's office bought this for me.

Comment: Contact customer support.